# Discord.py : How to keep \n in args when sending messages

Tags: python, arguments, discord.py, newline, function-parameter

I'm trying to create a command that formats your code on Discord with a given language,

by sending the formatted string:

````py
f"```{language}\n{code}\n```"
````

The function prototype is :

```py
def format(ctx, language, *code)
```

And I'm typing on Discord for example :

```
!format c int function(int x)
{
  return x;
}
```

But when I tried to print out the `code` arg, there is no `\n` in the list and the bot message is on a single line.

I also tried with quotation marks around my message, and this worked for keeping `\n` but if my code contains another quotation mark it ends the `code` arg, and throws an error for the remaining part.

Is there a way to get the complete message including newlines?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your OS sed option so you could get newline or tab characters back.

- All these characters (\n \t )are stored in the os system. So by changing them or removing them you could easily use them as parameters.
  Here is the solution:
  [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Comment: your answer is ok, but next time please refrain from adding links only to other answers, provide some code snippets referring to it here as well/

Comment: I didn't quite understand where's the solution with sed, the answers run the sed command on a file and replace newlines with something else.
But I don't have any file, my Discord command parameters are given to my function with the Discord API.

How could I run the sed command before my function ?